# JQuery Mobile custom icons doesn't show up in IOS simulator

Tags: xcode, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have added several custom icons to my buttons, and they work fine if I view them in a browser, but after I loaded it in Xcode using PhoneGap, they aren't shown anymore. There is simply just round circles and the images are not shown.

I have made sure the images are added to the solution, but do I need to somehow configure them to be embedded in the application?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I used to using absolute image paths, but this can't be done in PhoneGap. I changed the paths to be relative, and then it worked.

Comment: In my css file, this is the code, background-image: url(images/icons-36-black.png);

Still it wont work :(